# How to plot line with missing data points in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Example:

[image]

I want to plot a chart just like above one: a line with some missing data points, that means the line is discontinuous.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This depends on what your datafile looks like.  If you insert a blank space in your datafile, it won't connect those adjacent points (This is the easiest way):

consider:

```
 #datafile
 1 2
 2 3

 4 2
 5 3
```

and then the script to plot it:

```
 plot 'datafile' u 1:2 w linespoints
```

There are other tricks you can play with missing data:  `set datafile missing`.  A good reference for this is the builtin help (`help missing`).

Comment: Thanks, but my datafile doesn't just contain 2 columns:

Comment: Thanks, but my datafile contains many columns, only 1 of those columns has missing data point. So I can't add a blank line, this will cause other colums/lines discontinuous. Let me try to attach a separate file for this column, it might work.

Comment: @CharryWong -- That is where the `set datafile missing` part of my answer comes in.

Comment: I did try 'set datafile missing', the line is still continuous. But finally I figured it out, I can't use 'using 5', I need to use 'using ($5)'.

Comment: gnuplot doc: It should be noted that plot 'file', plot 'file' using 1:2, and plot 'file' using ($1):($2) can be subtly
different: 1) if file has some lines with one column and some with two, the first will invent x values when they
are missing, the second will quietly ignore the lines with one column, and the third will store an undefined
value for lines with one point (so that in a plot with lines, no line joins points across the bad point); 2) if
a line contains text at the first column, the first will abort the plot on an error, but the second and third
should quietly skip the garbage.

Comment: @CharryWong I think this would deserve to be a separate answer or edited into this answer. It is a crucial port and hidden in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

For a single plot, use `set datafile missing` to specify the character string that signifies a missing value, and the `using $` specifier to ensure that gnuplot leaves a gap in the line for a missing value.  The different `using` specifiers are described in the [gnuplot documentation for `set datafile missing`](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node172.html).

Where the column number is specified as a variable, this is a bit trickier.  For example, to plot multiple columns of a file one could specify the column number using a variable:

```
do for [i=2:10] {
    plot 'datafile' using ($1):i with lines
}
```

However, if we try to use the `$` syntax it doesn't work:

```
do for [i=2:10] {
    plot 'datafile' using ($1):($i) # ERROR!
}
```

The solution is to use the [column function](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node53.html), which also leaves blanks for missing values:

```
do for [i=2:10] {
    plot 'datafile' using ($1):(column(i)) with lines
}
```