# How to remove line between "jumping" values, in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to draw a line with plots that contain "jumping" values.

Here is an example: when we have plots of sin(x) for several cycles and plot it, unrealistic line will appear that go across from right to left (as shown in following figure).

One idea to avoid this might be using `with linespoints` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077340/how-to-plot-line-with-missing-data-points-in-gnuplot)), but I want to draw it without revising the original data file.

Do we have simple and robust solution for this problem?

[image: sample image]

Comment: Just put an empty line at the point where the abscissa values in your data file jump.

Comment: @Karl Thank you for you comment. but as I wrote in my questions, I would like to achieve it without revising the original file.

Comment: Didn't see that: "with linespoint" does the same as "with lines", only the points area added.

Comment: Otherwise: Impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are plotting a function, that is, for each x value there exists one and only one corresponding y value, the easiest way to achieve what you want is to use the `smooth unique` option. This smoothing routine will make the data monotonic in x, then plot it. When several y values exist for the same x value, the average will be used.

Example:

Data file:

```
0.5 0.5
1.0 1.5
1.5 0.5
0.5 0.5
```

Plotting without smoothing:

```
set xrange [0:2]
set yrange [0:2]
plot "data" w l
```

[image]

With smoothing:

```
plot "data" smooth unique
```

[image]

Comment: This is absolutely beautiful solution! Your method is simple/robust and powerful. Thank you for wonderful solution!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: points are lost if this solution is used, so I suggest to improve my answer.

Here can be applied "conditional plotting". Suppose we have a file like this:

```
1 2
2 5
3 3
1 2
2 5
3 3
```

i.e. there is a backline between 3rd and 4th point.

```
plot "tmp.dat" u 1:2
```

[image]

Find minimum x value:

```
stats "tmp.dat" u 1:2
prev=STATS_min_x
```

Or find first x value:

```
prev=system("awk 'FNR == 1 {print $1}' tmp.dat")
```

Plot the line if current x value is greater than previous, or don't plot if it's less:

```
plot "tmp.dat" u ($0==0? prev:($1>prev? $1:1/0), prev=$1):2 w l
```

[image]

Comment: @Karl Yes, I see it now.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it's not impossible, but the following is a ghastly hack. I really advise you add an empty line in your dataset at the breaks.

```
$dat << EOD
1 1
2 2
3 3
1 5
2 6
3 7
1 8
2 9
3 10
EOD

plot for [i=0:3] $dat us \
   ($0==0?j=0:j=j,llx=lx,lx=$1,llx>lx?j=j+1:j=j,i==j?$1:NaN):2 w lp notit
```

This plots your dataset three times (acually four, there is a small error in there. I guess i have to initialise all variables), counts how often the abscissa values "jump", and only plots datapoints if this counter `j` is equal to the plot counter `i`.

Check the help on the serial evaluation operator "a, b" and the ternary operator "a?b:c"

Answer (score 0):

If you have data in a repetitive x-range where the corresponding y-values **do *not*** change, then @Miguel's `smooth unique` solution is certainly the easiest.

In a more general case, what if the x-range is repetitive but y-values are changing, e.g. like a noisy `sin(x)`?

Then compare two consecutive x-values `x0` and `x1`, if `x0>x1` then you have a "jump" and make the linecolor fully transparent, i.e. invisible, e.g. `0xff123456` (scheme `0xaarrggbb`, check `help colorspec`). The same "trick" can be used when you want to interrupt a dataline which has a certain forward "jump" (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72535613/7295599).

**Minimal solution:**

```
plot x1=NaN $Data u 1:2:(x0=x1,x1=$1,x0>x1?0xff123456:0x0000ff) w l lc rgb var
```

**Script:**

```
### plot "folded" data without connecting lines
reset session

# create some test data
set table $Data
    plot [0:2*pi] for [i=1:4] '+' u 1:(sin(x)+rand(0)*0.5) w table
unset table

set xrange[0:2*pi]
set key noautotitle

set multiplot layout 1,2

    plot $Data u 1:2 w l lc "red" ti "data as is"

    plot x1=NaN $Data u 1:2:(x0=x1,x1=$1,x0>x1?0xff123456:0x0000ff) \
         w l lc rgb var ti "\n\n\"Jumps\" removed\nwithout changing\ninput data"
unset multiplot 
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]